# How to set the size of the keyboard for EditText

Tags: java, android, size, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I wonder whether it is possible to set the size of the keyboard for an editable text field? Is it possible to specify the size, even in relative terms, using existing tools, or is there any possibility to achieve statement of purpose? I hope for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, unless you have control over all the devices your app will run on (like an enterprise environment) and you install a custom keyboard.

Really, the only options you get for the onscreen keyboard are a few manifest entries about they [keyboard start state](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) (shown or hidden), and how your Activity responds/sizes itself when the onscreen keyboard is shown.